# How to create a 1-bit image in ios sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, image-processing, uiimageview

I want to convert an image to 1-bit image for ocr reading . I tried to replace the pixels depending upon its threshold but result is too dark and black I am using c++ library to that

```
ImageWrapper* Image::autoLocalThreshold() {
    const int local_size=8;
    // now produce the thresholded image
    uint8_t *result=(uint8_t*) malloc(m_width*m_height);
    // get the initial total
    int total=0;
    for(int y=0; y<local_size; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<local_size; x++) {
            total+=(*this)[y][x];
        }
    }
    // process the image
    int lastIndex=m_width*m_height-(m_width*local_size/2+local_size/2);
    for(int index=m_width*local_size/2+local_size/2; index<lastIndex; index++) {
        int threshold=total/64;
        if(m_imageData[index]>threshold*0.9)
            result[index]=0;
        else
            result[index]=255;
        // calculate the new total
        for(int index2=index-m_width*local_size/2-local_size/2; index2<index+m_width*local_size/2-local_size/2; index2+=m_width) {
            total-=m_imageData[index2];
            total+=m_imageData[index2+local_size];
        }
    }
    return Image::createImage(result, m_width, m_height, true);
}
```

Can anybody give me an idea how to do it properly and create a 1-bit image (black and white ) image ?

Thanks in advance .I will appreciate your help

Comment: It looks like you're using an adaptive threshold. To expand upon what Randy said, perhaps you could add an adjustment to the local threshold to bias it higher or lower and change which pixels pass the threshold. This should alter the tone of the image.